If a unitary operator is close to the identity, will it leave any state it acts on unchanged?
I have a question that feels obvious, but I have been having trouble proving it. In words, the question is: If a unitary is close to the identity, will it leave any state it acts on unchanged?
This, to me, would necessarily be the intuitive definition of a unitary "being close to the identity", so that's why I say it "feels obvious".
In physics notation: Consider a unitary, $\hat{U}$ which is assumed to be arbitrarily close to identity. In other words:
\begin{equation}
\hat{U} = \exp(- i \delta \hat{G} ) \approx \hat{\mathbb{I}}-i \delta \hat{G},
\end{equation}
for $\delta \ll 1$ and $\hat{G}$ Hermitian.
Now, I need to prove that, for any normalized state $|\psi\rangle$, the unitary $\hat{U}$ will change it at most by order $\epsilon$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
|\langle \psi| \hat{U}|\psi\rangle|^2 = 1 - \epsilon.
\end{equation}
In math (just in case it helps clarify what I'm after): Prove that for every $\epsilon<<1$ there exists a $\delta$ such that
\begin{equation}
|\langle \psi| \exp(- i \delta \hat{G})|\psi\rangle|^2 = 1 - \epsilon,
\end{equation}
for every normalized $|\psi\rangle$, i.e. $|\langle\psi|\psi\rangle|=1$.
I suspect $\delta$ should be something like $\sqrt{\epsilon}$. Furthermore, we can assume the spectrum of $\hat{G}$ is finite and completely positive (or completely negative). Thanks!
My attempts at solving the problem: I've tried the obvious move of expanding $\hat{U}$ inside the $|\langle...\rangle|^2$, but this leads to an expression of the form $1+\epsilon$, which is not what I'm after because we already know this fidelity is upper bounded by 1. I've also tried a few norms on unitaries to induce a distance metric and modify the idea of "close to the identity" such as the Frobenius norm, and the spectral norm. I'm trying to avoid the diamond norm, because it is often unwieldy. Any proofs where we say "assume $d(\hat{U},\hat{\mathbb{I}})\leq \delta$ therefore $|\langle \psi| \hat{U}|\psi\rangle|^2 = 1 - \epsilon$ would be totally acceptable as well.

What is wrong with "it will change the state slowly unless it's an Eigenstate of the operator"? Are you trying to do epsilontics on wave functions? You also seem to be moving backwards here because you already seem to know that the exponential form is the solution for the finite operator that derives from an infinitesimal generator. What's wrong with using that to derive the solution?

I am assuming the state is acted on by this unitary, and I want to know if the unitary is close to the identity then, explicitly, how much does the state change-- even if it is a really small amount. I'd rather not make arguments about the state "changing slowly" because I want the explicit form of how much it changes by.

You already wrote it out explicitly: it changes by the exponential of your infinitesimal.

Sure, changes by the exponential of my infinitesimal. But I am trying to show precisely that it doesn't change more than a small amount. I think it's obvious if I set $\delta=0$ then the overlap $|\langle \psi| U |\psi\rangle|^2$ is $1$. But now I want $0<\delta\ll 1$ and I'd like to lower bound the overlap with $1-\epsilon$. This would use the fact that the state changes by the exponential of my infinitesimal in order to answer how the overlap probability changes.

But it does change by more than a small amount. The exponential is the formal integral that expresses the finite action of your generator. You are staring right at the concrete solution.

I'm not trying to be dense here, I really hope I am staring at the concrete solution! But, explicitly, as I take the limit that $\delta \rightarrow 0$ then surely $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ as well, and that implies it does change by only a small amount, for a sufficiently small $\delta$. These limit arguments surely hold because Lie groups are nice, continuous & connected near the identity. Where are you getting that it does change by more than a small amount?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I assume that the spectrum of $G=G^*$ stays in $[0,+\infty)$ and $\Lambda \leq +\infty$ is an upper bound of it.
$$\langle \psi |e^{-i\delta G} \psi\rangle =  \langle\psi|\psi\rangle+
\langle \psi |(e^{-i\delta G}-I) \psi\rangle
 =\langle\psi|\psi\rangle + \delta \int_0^\Lambda \frac{e^{-i\delta \lambda}-1}{\delta} d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle\:.$$
If $\psi \in D(\sqrt{G})$ (that just means every $\psi$ in the Hilbert space if $\Lambda < +\infty$), we can estimate
$$\left| \int_0^\Lambda \frac{e^{-i\delta \lambda}-1}{\delta} d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle\right|\leq  \int_0^\Lambda \left|\frac{e^{-i\delta \lambda}-1}{\delta}\right| d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle$$
$$=  \int_0^\Lambda \lambda \sqrt{\left(\frac{\cos \delta \lambda -1}{\delta \lambda}\right)^2+ \left(\frac{\sin \delta \lambda }{\delta \lambda}\right)^2} d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle
=  \int_0^\Lambda \lambda \sqrt{\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x' } d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle
\leq\sqrt{2} \int_0^\Lambda \lambda  d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle = \sqrt{2} \langle \psi|G\psi\rangle
$$ where $x,x' \in [0, \delta\lambda]$, so that
$$\left| \int_0^\Lambda \frac{e^{-i\delta \lambda}-1}{\delta} d \langle \psi| P^{(G)}(\lambda)\psi \rangle\right|\leq   \sqrt{2} \langle \psi| G\psi\rangle\:.$$
In summary, defining $ E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)$ implicitly by
$$\langle \psi |e^{-i\delta G} \psi\rangle = \langle\psi|\psi\rangle + \delta E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)\:,\tag{E}$$
we have
$$| E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)|\leq \sqrt{2\langle \psi|G\psi \rangle}\:.$$
Finally, if $G$ is bounded, we also have the estimate
$$\sqrt{2\langle \psi|G\psi \rangle}\leq ||\psi|| \sqrt{2||G||}\:.$$
Let us fix the $1-\delta$ issue.
I explicitly suppose that $||\psi||=1$. In this case $$|\langle \psi |e^{-i\delta G} \psi\rangle|\leq ||\psi||\: ||e^{-i\delta G} \psi|| = ||\psi||^2 =1\tag{M}$$ because the operator is unitary. As a consequence, from (E),
$$|\langle \psi |e^{-i\delta G} \psi\rangle|^2  = 1 + \delta^2 |E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)|^2 + \delta 2 Re(E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi))$$
where $$\delta^2 |E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)|^2 + \delta 2 Re(E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi))\leq  0$$ for every $\delta>0$, otherwise (M) is impossible. In conclusion
$$|\langle \psi |e^{-i\delta G} \psi\rangle|^2  = 1 - \delta H^{(G)}(\delta, \psi) $$
where, for $\delta\geq 0$, $$0\leq H^{(G)}(\delta, \psi) := \left( -\delta |E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)|^2 -  2 Re(E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi))\right)\leq 2 |E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)| \leq 2 \sqrt{2\langle \psi|G\psi \rangle}< +\infty\:.$$

But does this give the $1-\epsilon$ on the RHS the OP seems to want to have (with $\epsilon >0$, I suppose)?

I do not know, I have "interpreted" the question.

I see. I also thought about answering it, and also found some bound similar to yours, IIRC, but refrained from posting because of the "minus sign issue". Perhaps I am missing something obvious, though.

Thanks for the answer Valter! I want to make sure I understand it fully before I comment on if this avoids the minus sign issue I've ran into. So I'm going to ask some obvious but improtant clarifying questions. First, $P^{(G)}(\lambda)$ is the projector onto the eigenstate with eigenvalue $\lambda$, correct? Second, $E^{(G)}(\delta, \psi)$ is defined implicitly via that inequality, and serves as the stand in for what I called $\epsilon$, right?

$P^{(G)}(\Delta)$ is the spectral measure of $G$. Yes, in case of point spectrum, $\Delta$ are sets of proper eigenvalues. $E^{(G)}(\delta,\psi)$ is defined implicitly in the text as made clearer now.

Hi Valter, I think your answer reduces to the same limits of 1+epsilon that I have been finding! But, I upvoted your answer for finding those limits in a much better way that my original approach. After some extended chatting in which I attempted to provide some extra context for this problem, I've decided to move this to either math SE or quantum computing SE. If there's no resolution there and this ends up being the closest/best answer I'll be sure to come back and mark this as correct. Thank you

@John I am not sure to understand your issue. Now there is no epsilon, only $\delta$, that is $\epsilon=\delta$. Do you think that there is a better estimate?

After reading your last edit, I believe this has answered my question! Explicitly making use of the fact that $|\langle \psi| U \psi \rangle|<1$ to explicitly make these terms negative, and then using the bounds we've just put on them is the crucial step I was missing. I've marked your answer as accepted! Thank you, this turned out to be far more subtle to me than I expected, given the "no duh" nature of the claim.

@ValterMoretti, one last thing, we can directly bound $\sqrt{ \left( \frac{ \cos(\lambda \delta) - 1}{\lambda \delta} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{ \sin(\lambda \delta)}{\lambda \delta} \right)^2 } \leq 1$ either just by checking it graphically or using the limit as $ (\lambda \delta) \rightarrow 0$. This (trivially) improves the bound you have, which uses $\sqrt{ \left( \frac{ \cos(\lambda \delta) - 1}{\lambda \delta} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{ \sin(\lambda \delta)}{\lambda \delta} \right)^2 } \leq \sqrt{2}$, but it is always nice to toss extra factors of 2 so I figured I'd point it out.

Thank you! I never realised it.

Here is a very simple lower bound for the fidelity, maybe this helps in addition to the existing answer:
Let $U=\exp(-i\delta G)$, then using Duhamel's formula one can show the inequality $|| \exp(A) - \exp(B)|| \leq ||A - B||$ with the operator norm $||\cdot||$ (for a proof, see for instance Lemma 1 here). This yields $||\mathbb{I} - U|| \leq \delta ||G||$ and finally
$$1 - \langle \psi | U | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \mathbb{I} - U | \psi \rangle \leq ||\mathbb{I} - U|| \leq \delta ||G||. $$
Rearranging yields a fidelity lower bound $|\langle \psi | U | \psi \rangle|^2 \geq (1 - \delta ||G||)^2$. There are known tightness results, whenever $\delta$ is small enough (compared to $||G||$).

This answer is really good

Thanks man! . .
